# Trying to use grid computing or distributed computing in C#

Tags: c#, distributed

I have seen many questions on here on this subject but all of the projects that people have posted about seem to be dead or don't work with my system. I'm trying to write an application for a school project to calculate the numbers of pi using my desktop and laptop. Can anyone please help post a url to a project where I can use distributed computing using the computers in my local network.

I have tried the following but no luck so far:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71897/Grid-Computing-Using-C-Script-and-NET-Remoting
(project doesn't work after doing one way upgrade in visual studio 2013. this does seem to be exactly what I'm looking for but it won't build out of the box because in the PiCalculationManager project it has a reference error for the RemoteClass reference. It has a yellow icon and getting 4 errors for not being able to find the namespace it is using)

http://mpapi.codeplex.com/
(distributed project doesn't work because it won't connect with the registration server)

https://github.com/tylerjensen/duovia-distributed
(can't seem to figure out the implementation and how to connect to the other computers on my local network)

If you have any suggestions or questions please let me know. I don't seem to be getting anywhere with this project

Comment: This is probably a bit too broad of a question, so your answers will be of varying quality and probably unhelpful. If you can you reword your question to ask about one of those things you mentioned (like the compile error you get from the first one), you may get better and more focused assistance.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will edit now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been digging for awhile on .NET grid computing and finally I decide to build my own. Still in beta but it's stable now :) Take a look at: http://lucygrid.codeplex.com/

I wrote the PI example in the demo project. I'll try keep usability as much easy as possible so you just only need to use AsParallelGrid function (there's a built in node with the library that will process each chunk, but of course you will need to run independent nodes on other machines to test the grid)

The code is open source so feel free to play with it.

From LucyDemo project:

```
public string Run(bool enableLocalProcessing)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double step = 1.0 / (double)Steps;

    /* ORIGINAL VERSION
    object obj = new object();

    Parallel.ForEach(
        Partitioner.Create(0, Steps),
        () => 0.0,
        (range, state, partial) =>
        {
            for (long i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
            {
                double x = (i - 0.5) * step;
                partial += 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
            }
            return partial;
        },
        partial => { lock (obj) sum += partial; });
    */

    sum = Enumerable
        .Range(0, Steps)
        // Create bucket
        .GroupBy(s => s / 50)
        // Local variable initialization is not distributed over the grid
        .Select(i => new 
        {
            Item1 = i.First(),
            Item2 = i.Last() + 1, // Inclusive
            Step = step
        })
        .AsParallelGrid(data =>
        {
            double partial = 0;
            for (var i = data.Item1; i != data.Item2 ; ++i)
            {
                double x = (i - 0.5) * data.Step;
                partial += (double)(4.0 / (1.0 + x * x));
            }
            return partial;
        }, new GridSettings()
        {
            EnableLocalProcessing = enableLocalProcessing
        })
        .Sum() * step;

    return sum.ToString();
}
```

I'm posting the Parallel version and the Grid one. 
I'll be glad to know if you try it.